# Multiple sets of "nextPage"s

Tags: javascript, html, button, gallery

First and for most, I am new to web coding and more or less just teaching myself when I have free time... so I apologize if I make little sense.

I essentially have a simple javascript that allows me to have a prev and next button to move through multiple images. However I wanted to have multiple of these sets of "galleries" but in my case they interact with each other. I've attempted to contain each section (gallery, small text box, and the two buttons) but I've had no luck.

If you follow my link bellow you can see my issue... depending on the size of your screen you may only see one gallery, but you can see the each set of buttons affects each gallery.. This also for some reason adds "blank" images into the list of the image galleries.

http://robinwkurtz.com/slider/issue.html

Thanks in advanced!

This is my source code

```
<div class="section black" id="top_ten">       
<div id="title"><h1>TOP TEN</h1></div>          
<div id="image">
    <div class="container">
        <ol>
            <li><img src="images/project5_1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/project5_2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/project5_3.jpg"></li>
        </ol>
      <div id="contentfooter">
        <div id="footer">A publication and poster, which teaches guide lines to technical constraints. With any design job there comes rules and guidelines to follow in order to put out a proper project.</div>
            <span class="button prevButton">&#8211;</span>
            <span  class="button nextButton">+</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    var pages = $('.container ol li'), current=0;
    var currentPage,nextPage;

    $('.button').click(function(){
        currentPage= pages.eq(current);
        if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
        {

            if (current <= 0)
                current=pages.length-1;
            else
                current=current-1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current >= pages.length-1)
                current=0;
            else
                current=current+1;
        }
        nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
        currentPage.hide(); 
        nextPage.show();        
    });
```

});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net - setup a small example of the problem so it's easier to work with. Only include enough to demonstrate the problem and no more.

Comment: Sorry about that, this should be more simple

http://robinwkurtz.com/slider/issue.html

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID `#container`. Only one element can have an ID. Make it a class if you want to give it to multiple elements.

Now, when you select `pages`, you're selecting all of them.

```
var pages = $('#container ol li')
```

That would select every li inside and ol inside #container (it would be every container but it's an ID so that's causing you problems, too).

You know which button you clicked using `$(this)` so you can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to go up the DOM and find the container that contains that button and set of pages and only select that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the whole class verse ID thing and it seems very obvious to me know that you point it out! However where I get lose is how to tell my javascript to effect all these classes without lets say repeating the whole scrpit several times.

Thanks again

Comment: `$('.button').click` already does that. You just need to, inside of that, figure out WHICH button was clicked and only change the images for that group.